# Understand 'this' in a callback function

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var a = ["a","a"]
a.name = "a"

unique(a)
function unique(arr){
    arr.filter(function(e){
        console.log(this.name) // undefined
    })
}
```

The result is undefined and I am wondering what is 'this' referring to in this case and what can I do to make 'this.name' actually print something instead of undefined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [documentation for `Array#filter` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to understand why `this` is undefined:

> arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])
>
> If a thisArg parameter is provided to filter, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

You need to set the `thisArg` explicitly by giving `Array#filter` a context via a second argument:

```
function unique(arr){
    arr.filter(function(e){
        console.log(this.name);
    }, arr);
}
```